# Swift function func in another func doesn't work twice

Tags: swift, animation, uikit

there is a piece of Swift code

```
import UIKit class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var sphere: UIImageView!
@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        }


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func stepUpDown(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    let t = Double(sender.value)
    animateSphere(timOfDel: t, xTransaktion: 120)
    //animateSphere(timOfDel: t, xTransaktion: -120) //**QUESTION ABOUT THIS**
    print("time duration \(t)")
}


private func animateSphere(timOfDel: Double, xTransaktion: Double) {
    let options: UIView.AnimationOptions = [.curveEaseInOut]

   
    UIView.animate(withDuration: timOfDel,
                   delay: 0,
                   options: options,
                   animations: { [weak self] in
                    self?.sphere.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: CGFloat(xTransaktion), y: 0)
                    
    }, completion: nil)
} }
```

question is: why when I uncomment func `animateSphere()` emulator shows last, second state of the function?

Comment: The animation gets cut off/stopped. By the second function. If you put a delay between the two you’ll see them both.

Comment: You change transform with an animation. Then immediately you change transform with another animation. That does not mean that the second one will wait for the first animation to complete. It would be better to run the second animation from the completion handler, or at least adding a delay for the second animation.
This will work the same in any language.

Comment: it means that to second animation needs just add delay number? I mean, third parameter aka delay?

Comment: It means that the second animation has to be started when the first animation ends. There are several ways to do that.

Comment: But now second animation not wait first.

Comment: private func animateSphere(timeOfAnimation: Double, xTransaktion: Double, delayTime: Double) {} not works :(

Answer (score 1):

Okay, last method works, but much better use to simple animation  .center method, like
self?.sphere.center = CGPoint(x: gotoX, y: gotoY)